# BizTalk BAM Portal "Related Documents" Missing

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I am working with BizTalk 2010 and using the BAM API to record the body of an incoming message in the BAM_Itinerary_CompletedRelationships table of the BAMPrimaryImport database. This is working well and through SSMS I can see the inbound XML message in the LongReferenceData column. I was hoping to see link to this in the "Related Documents" section of the BAM Portal, but this is empty.

Does anyone know how to get this data to be displayed in the BAM portal?

I'd rather not write a custom / SSRS UI if I can avoid it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the API you should be able to achieve that using the AddReference method with a type of DocumentUrl - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa956649.aspx

This blog might also have some useful info for you - http://geekswithblogs.net/gwiele/archive/2009/05/28/132469.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: I am using the AddReference method to get the message body into the LongReferenceData column, problem is this doesn't seem to be read by the BAM Portal. However, the link you sent looks very promising, I'll try this at the weekend and let you know.

Comment: I am delighted to report, it works! Bravo http://geekswithblogs.net/gwiele/archive/2009/05/28/132469.aspx